Bluetooth HD sound not working after update
I've a laptop that I use to work daily. Some days ago, I got an update (as usual) but since then my headphones (Senn. Momentum 4) can't pair via Bluetooth. The weird thing is that my old headphones (Sony CH710N) work as usual. As far as I've seen, the main difference is the audio codec, Senn. uses aptx HD, Sony uses SBC low resolution audio. In bluetooth status I see a "Connection refused" error. The only way of making it work is to remove the Senn. and pair it again, every time...
So, what I've seen until now:
OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS x86_64
Kernel: 6.8.0-51-generic
CPU: Intel i5-1035G1 (8) @ 3.600GHz
Bluetooth: Realtek RTL8822CE
sudo service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-12-19 08:02:50 CET; 3h 16min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1320 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18723)
     Memory: 3.4M (peak: 3.9M)
        CPU: 14.109s
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1320 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

dic 19 08:03:19 Laptop bluetoothd[1320]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.80 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/opus_05_duplex
dic 19 08:03:19 Laptop bluetoothd[1320]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.80 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05_duplex
dic 19 08:18:21 Laptop bluetoothd[1320]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_74_43_CF_CD_B9_1E/sep1/fd0: fd(32) ready
dic 19 08:25:54 Laptop bluetoothd[1320]: src/profile.c:ext_connect() Hands-Free Voice gateway failed connect to <MAC>: Connection refused (111)
dic 19 08:25:55 Laptop bluetoothd[1320]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:avdtp_connect_cb() connect to <MAC>: Connection refused (111)
dic 19 08:25:56 Laptop bluetoothd[1320]: src/profile.c:ext_connect() Hands-Free Voice gateway failed connect to <MAC>: Connection refused (111)
dic 19 08:25:56 Laptop bluetoothd[1320]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:avdtp_connect_cb() connect to <MAC>: Connection refused (111)

EDIT: Adding more information to the topic:
sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
[    0.328863] ACPI: thermal: [Firmware Bug]: Invalid critical threshold (-274000)
[    0.566846] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:02: [Firmware Info]: 8F1F6436-9F42-42C8-BADC-0E9424F20C9A has zero instances
[    0.566848] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:02: [Firmware Info]: 8F1F6435-9F42-42C8-BADC-0E9424F20C9A has zero instances
[    0.566850] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:02: [Firmware Info]: 7391A661-223A-47DB-A77A-7BE84C60822D has zero instances
[    0.566851] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:02: [Firmware Info]: DF4E63B6-3BBC-4858-9737-C74F82F821F3 has zero instances
[    1.200636] usb 1-10: Product: Bluetooth Radio
[   21.269257] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   21.269441] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[   21.269443] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   21.269447] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   21.269450] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   21.269454] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   21.769590] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/icl_dmc_ver1_09.bin (v1.9)
[   21.779554] rtw_8822ce 0000:01:00.0: WOW Firmware version 9.9.4, H2C version 15
[   21.779799] rtw_8822ce 0000:01:00.0: Firmware version 9.9.15, H2C version 15
[   21.842860] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0a hci_rev=000c lmp_ver=0a lmp_subver=8822
[   21.843816] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=3
[   21.843836] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8822cu_fw.bin
[   21.847076] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8822cu_config.bin
[   21.847616] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 6, total sz 35990
[   22.051592] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x0cc6d2e3
[   22.147049] Bluetooth: hci0: AOSP extensions version v1.00
[   22.147055] Bluetooth: hci0: AOSP quality report is supported
[   23.826305] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   23.826313] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   23.826319] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   23.829135] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[   23.907946] Bluetooth: hci0: Invalid link address type 1 for <MAC>
[   23.915988] Bluetooth: hci0: Bad flag given (0x1) vs supported (0x0)
[   24.520057] hid-generic 0005:046D:B033.0002: input,hidraw1: BLUETOOTH HID v0.10 Mouse [LIFT B] on <MAC>
[   31.765446] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   31.765456] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   31.765463] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11

Manually pairing using bluetoothctl had same issues.
bluetoothctl 
remove <MAC_ADDRESS>

Pair the headphones again:
pair <MAC_ADDRESS>
trust <MAC_ADDRESS>
connect <MAC_ADDRESS>

Verify the connection status:
info <MAC_ADDRESS>

Same error, connection refused after rebooting...
Has someone experienced something similar? Any workaround?
It's my first time posting a question... please, let me know if something more is needed...

I've just done:
sudo rm /var/lib/bluetooth/* -rf sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
No luck... after this I reinstalled bluez:
sudo apt remove --purge bluez sudo apt install bluez sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
But the issue is still there...

Can you boot into the 6.8.0-49 kernel or older and see if it works

Thanks for the idea @Jeremy31 , Kernel 6.8.0-45-generic seems to work...

What results for sudo dmesg | egrep-i'blue|firm'

I've added the results to the question itself...
